# IIS7: How to restrict virtual directory access to specific IP

Tags: iis-7, virtual-directory

I have a site set up in IIS, and I have a virtual directory that should only be available to localhost.

In IIS6, this was trivial to set up.

However, those property sheets are gone in IIS7 and I cannot find a corresponding setting. RequestFiltering and denyURLSequence isn't right, because that doesn't have an attribute for IP, at least, not that I could find.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need IIS module called "**IP and Domain Restrictions**" (bundled with IIS) .. or grab improved version: **[Dynamic IP Restrictions](http://www.iis.net/download/DynamicIPRestrictions)**.

Once installed configure to block all IPs except selected (should be no problems at all -- very easy GUI).

Answer (score 0):

You can include the following code block inside your web.config file of the virtual directory to restrict access only to localhost.

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

If you already have the system.webServer block, then you need to add only the security block.

Comment: You would still have to make sure that the `IP and Domain Restrictions` module is installed in IIS for that to work.

Comment: Thanks sparx. I tried this, but it seemed as if IIS wasn't picking up on the existence of the file. In fact, I had changed several things in applicationHosts.config as well and those changes weren't noticed, either. I have feature delegation turned on (I think), so no idea what was going on.